# What is the equation for the graphic featured on the wiki for periodic functions?

Tags: periodic-functions

The [Wiki on Periodic Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) has this graphic:

[image]

What equation would produce that function?

Comment: $f(x)=\left| \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right| +1$ gives something similar. Your example is more complicated, tho.

Comment: I have not seen any relatively-common functions that look as such; it's entirely possible that they drew up a semi-random shape and repeated it. This may not have any significant.